# Is it the best way to pick certain values from related tables with MAX()?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

So here is my code

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.place, acc.name, acc.balance 
FROM withdrawals w
INNER JOIN acc ON w.user_id = acc.user_id
WHERE acc.balance = (
    SELECT MAX(acc.balance) FROM withdrawals
    INNER JOIN acc ON withdrawals.user_id = acc.user_id
    GROUP BY withdrawals.place
    HAVING withdrawals.place = w.place
)
```

Im wondering what's the quickest way to retrieve few informations from related tables, having them grouped by specific value.
I'm complete freshman in terms of writing in SQL. I'm used to programming languages though, that's probably why my mind tries to contrive it in loops and conditionals.
I would really appreciate complex explanation.

Comment: MySQL5.x or MySQL8+? How do you want to handle ties?

Comment: ties should stay, we want all values equal to maximum

Comment: There's no need for `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` in the subquery. Just use `WHERE withdrawals.place = w.place`

Comment: ***MySQL5.x or MySQL8+?***

Comment: So subquery will automatically find the maximal value withdrawn in certain place?

Comment: Because the place is specified in the WHERE clause, it will be restricted to accounts which made withdrawals at that place, yes. To learn more, search for `correlated sub-query`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here but it looks that if you get rid of the whole `where`, add the max on the query and add the group by it will return the same thing? (since you are using distinct) as in: `select w.place, acc.name, max(MAX(acc.balance)) as balance from..... group by w.place, acc.name`

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8+, look in to ROW_NUMBER(). But you don't seem to want to answer my question?

Comment: sorry, I generally mean SQL language I don't want to use additional methods at the moment

Comment: Window functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` are standard in the SQL language, but MySQL didn't implement window functions until MySQL 8. But not everyone has upgraded to MySQL 8 (despite it being available since 2018), hence the question about which version you are using. If someone asks you a simple question for clarification, you should answer it.